# Optimizing Chess Game in C

Tags: c, optimization, chess

I'm making a simple chess game in C and I wanted to know about the optimizations I could make to it. Currently, I have a struct Game that has the current state of the game (Main Menu, Pause Menu, Playing etc), the turn, 3 integers that work as booleans, pointer to a board and pointer to the selected piece:

```
typedef struct game{
    ChessBoard *board;
    ChessPiece *selectedPiece;

    ChessColor turn;
    State state;

    //Booleans
    int inGame;
    int checkmate;
    int check;
}Game;
```

The Board has a 2D array of pointers to pieces, the players and the last moved pieces (for en passant):

```
typedef struct chessboard{
    ChessPiece *pieces[8][8];

    Player *player1;
    Player *player2;

    ChessPiece *lastMovedBlackPiece;
    ChessPiece *lastMovedWhitePiece;
} ChessBoard;
```

And finally the piece:

```
typedef struct chesspiece{
    //Properties
    int x;
    int y;
    ChessColor color;

    //Type
    Type type;

    int numberOfMoves;
} ChessPiece;
```

Each time the player selects a piece, the program calculates and shows the valid moves of the selected piece, and after moving a piece the program verifies whether the enemy king is in check or it was checkmate by checking the possible moves of the pieces (if a piece can protect him, if the king can move elsewhere).

I see people creating lists for valid moves instead of calculating every time, but I'd have to create a list for every piece and calculate all the possible moves for a player when the turn changes? Would that improve the performance? I also saw the board being just an array, would that have greater performance as well?

Basically, which are the possible optimizations I can do in my code for better performance?

The code: https://github.com/WalrusNine/chess-game-c

Comment: It's difficult to suggest improvements to your code without seeing it.

Comment: @PM I was thinking about general, known-optimizations for chess games, as I did no optimization at all, and there are some parts of my code that really (really) need a change haha, but anyways: https://github.com/WalrusNine/chess-game-c After the code is better I'm planning on giving it to some friends to help them learn a bit of games in C. It's using Allegro btw

Comment: As posted your question is too broad for this site.

Comment: @PM Are there any well known tips that could help me? If it's still too broad, I'd like to know about the two questions I asked (lists of possible moves vs calculate every time and array of pieces instead of 2D array). Or would you recommend another site?

Comment: you might want to look at the min/max algorithms and alpha/beta pruning algorithms.    BTW: the code would be a LOT more readable if you eliminated the typedef modifiers on the struct definitions (the preferred method is to not use typedef's as they just clutter/obscure  the code, clutter the compiler namespace, and can be very misleading to the human reader.)

Comment: I browsed the code for main,.c and game.c .  in C, the returned value from malloc() (and family of functions) should not be cast.  The returned value from malloc() and family should always be checked (!= NULL) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: when calling scanf() and family, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  The user could easily overrun the input buffers,  place a length limiter on the conversion parameters to avoid the overrun problem.

Comment: in this function: 'void InitializeBoard(ChessBoard *board){'  if board is NULL, the initialization is skipped, however, there is no effort to recover from this error, nor is the error information propagated back to the caller/rest of the game.

Comment: @user3629249 I still have to take AI classes so I'm leaving the AI part for later xD. But man these programming tips are awesome, is there a site or a book that cover these details and helps improving the code? Anyways I'll improve the code in the areas you pointed out, thanks!

Comment: Guys... The program should be optimised by chess algorithms. Doing those little things will never work. In particular, you might want to look at alpha-beta, PVS, pruning etc.

Comment: Whatever else you do, [*do this*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771). You might find, for example, 50% or more of your time going into `malloc` and `free`. If you find that (but not before), there's a simple fix. (It will speed you up by a factor of 1 over 1 minus the fraction of time it takes.) Other things also could have simple fixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically, which are the possible optimizations I can do in my code
>   for better performance?

This is a broad and deep topic.  I've written a fully functional chess engine in Java (https://github.com/amir650/BlackWidow-Chess) and I can tell you, there are a lot of things you can do.

Start by reading: https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com.  First focus on the correctness of your engine.  Does it handle castling, en-passant, check, checkmate, discovered check, etc.  Without getting this correct, performance doesn't matter!

Next write a [minimax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) and evaluation function - which serve as your basic search procedure, and measure the number of boards it can evaluate for you per second.

From there, things start to open up:

```
1) Alpha Beta Pruning
2) Board representation (bit-board vs array)
3) Null Move Heuristic
4) DB for opening
5) DB end engame
6) Transposition tables
7) ..it goes on
```

Whatever optimizations you do, make sure correctness does not regress. This means having decent unit tests written.